# React Native with TypeScript and cucumber-js: Importing TypeScript Functions into Cucumber Step Definitions

Tags: typescript, react-native, cucumber, commonjs, ts-node

As the title states, I'm looking to test some functions we use in a React Native app. Indeed, in the future I would like to write business functions *based* on our cucumber tests - so ideally my dev workflow would begin with me creating a test in our code base and wrestling with it until it meets all tests. However, I'm running into a problem that whenever I import said functions from our codebase, cucumber breaks and the tests don't run. So far, using `detox` for end-to-end testing has worked fine (interacting with elements via `TestID` and so on), but in a recent set of tests, I was trying to call a function explicitly, and this is where we start to run into errors.

We allow for cucumber tests in TypeScript by writing the following in our `cucumber.js` file:

```js
let common = [
   'features/**/*.feature',                // Specify our feature files
   '--require-module ts-node/register',    // Load TypeScript module
   '--require features/support/**/*.ts',   // Load support files
   '--require step_definitions/**/*.ts',   // Load step definitions
].join(' ');

module.exports = {
  default: common,
};
```

However, in my `step_definitions`, as soon as I try and import a function from our React Native project, I start getting errors like this one, for example from `react-native`:

```
/Users/file/path/to/project/here/node_modules/react-native/index.js:14
import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/file/path/to/project/here/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1300:43)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/file/path/to/project/here/src/helpers/utils.ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/file/path/to/project/here/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1310:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/file/path/to/project/here/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1313:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
codepath: /Users/file/path/to/project/here/step_definitions/5-Chat/2-1-chat-deletion-indicator.steps.ts
```

I see here that the commonjs (`cjs`) module is firing the error. I understand that React Native is written for ES6, so commonjs is wrong in the first place. What I *don't* know how to do is keep my fancy `cucumber.js` setup file and the ability to keep my tests (and imported functions) in TypeScript without `ts-node` complaining.

Any assistance, pointers, or ideas here would be greatly appreciated. I'll be glad to include any other configs and files needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tests on single functions (in this case these are unit tests), I have since begun to use [`jest-cucumber`](https://github.com/bencompton/jest-cucumber) - this has it's own configuration and does not need use of such `cucumber.js` file. This `cucumber.js` file pattern is from using cucumber with an E2E framework like detox.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference for others, I'll share that it was pretty simple to set up `jest-cucumber` with `detox` for E2E tests, in addition to unit tests. (Well, detox was kind of involved to set up, but jest-cucumber was simple once detox was in place.) Below are the feature, steps, page, and config files for a proof-of-concept E2E test.

I'm going to look into how I can use more TypeScript within these tests, possibly with [`ts-jest`](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest), but I'm happy with this as a functional starting point. (I have these running and passing on iOS and Android simulators/emulators.)

Note:

- I'm using `require` instead of `import` to handle CommonJS modules for now.
- Inside `beforeAll`, the `device` object is a global that comes from detox.
- The detox page interaction/matcher calls are wrapped in `async` functions inside the given/when/then steps.

`e2e/features/auth/Login.feature`

```
Feature: Login

Scenario: Navigating to home screen
    Given I am on the login screen
    When I tap the login button
    Then I should see the home screen
```

`e2e/steps/Login.steps.js`

```
const { defineFeature, loadFeature } = require('jest-cucumber')

const HomePage = require('../pages/Home')
const LoginPage = require('../pages/Login')

const feature = loadFeature('e2e/features/auth/Login.feature')

defineFeature(feature, test => {
  let loginPage
  let homePage

  beforeAll(async () => {
    await device.launchApp()
    await device.reloadReactNative()
    loginPage = new LoginPage()
    homePage = new HomePage()
  })

  test('Navigating to home screen', ({ given, when, then }) => {
    given('I am on the login screen', async () => {
      await expect(loginPage.logInButton).toBeVisible()
    })

    when('I tap the login button', async () => {
      await loginPage.logInButton.tap()
    })

    then('I should see the home screen', async () => {
      await expect(homePage.helloText).toBeVisible()
    })
  })
})
```

`e2e/pages/Home.js`

```
module.exports = class HomePage {
  get helloText() {
    return element(by.text('Hello'))
  }
}
```

`e2e/pages/Login.js`

```
module.exports = class LoginPage {
  get logInButton() {
    return element(by.text('Log In'))
  }
}
```

`e2e/jest-e2e.config.json`

```
{
  "maxWorkers": 1,
  "testEnvironment": "./environment",
  "testRunner": "jest-circus/runner",
  "testMatch": ["**/*.steps.js"],
  "testTimeout": 120000,
  "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
  "verbose": true
}
```

`.detoxrc.json`

```
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/jest-e2e.config.json",
  //...
}
```